# ReSharper Compound Collection Initializer Formatting

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I am trying to figure out a formatting issue with collection initializers.  We have ReSharper set so that initializers get chopped, such that this:

```
var list = new List<string>
{
    "This", "That", "Other"
};
```

... would be reformatted to this:

```
var list = new List<string>
{
    "This",
    "That",
    "Other"
};
```

This is great for simple collections.  However, I can't seem to find a way for making an exception for compound initializers.  Consider this scenario:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "1", "One" }, { "2", "Two" }, { "3", "Three" }
}
```

We would like for the autoformatting to change the above to this:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "1", "One" },
    { "2", "Two" },
    { "3", "Three" }
}
```

However, because of the initializer chopping rule that makes the List look right, the Dictionary ends up like this:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {
        "1", "One"
    },
    {
        "2", "Two"
    },
    {
        "3", "Three"
    }
}
```

In any case, this formatting seems strange because it seems like if it were applying the same rule for initializers all the way down, we should end up with something like this (even more horrid):

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {
        "1",
        "One"
    },
    {
        "2",
        "Two"
    },
    {
        "3",
        "Three"
    }
}
```

So my question is, what rule or combination of rules can be set to get the desired formatting for the above Dictionary (and similar initializers)?

We're using ReSharper 10, Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Have you consider using the new dictionary initializers for C# 6.  `["1"] = "One"`.

Comment: Let me test how that wraps.  That might work well for Dictionaries.  Though, I'm wondering if there are other cases where the above formatting problem exists and this syntax isn't an option.

Comment: @juharr - That format does work for Dictionaries and does not trigger any unpleasant formatting.  However, I am still hoping someone might be able to answer the question using rule settings.  I'm going to go with this for my problem at hand, though.

Comment: Yeah, you'd probably have a similar issue with something like `List<List<T>>`.  That's why I didn't post that as an answer.